# Is title tag position relevant in html pages?

Tags: html, tags, position, head

I'd like know if having the title tag positioned at the end of <head> tag or in any other position, always inside the <head></head>, can lead to some kind of problem, I'm not talking about SEO stuffs, I'm talking about standards, browser rules, web application rules, or something like this.

I'd like to load a page from two different php file like this, is it a wrong way?

```
<!-- file1.php -->
<html>
<head> 
....

<!-- file2.php -->
<title><?php echo($var)?>
</head> 
<body>
...
```

<head> tag is not closed, because with e second file I dynamically add the <title>
tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title must be in the `<head>`

If you use non-ASCII in it then it really should be *after* any `<meta>` that specifies character encoding.

Since it is important, it is probably a good idea to put it near the top of the `<head>` so it gets picked up by tools that only grab the first $n bytes of the document.